# Connecting a cell of array in a view created in the main storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift2

I used the `ExpandTableView` of this repository on Github:

Repo -> https://github.com/SubhiH/ExpandableTableView

I need know how i connect a position of the array of this expandable view in a View in the Main storyboard, example:

[Image of the ExpandableTableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUfi.png)

I want that when a User click for example in the cell a1 user is sent to a TableView (View) on Main storyboard.
Any ideas?

Comment: " in the cell Num 1"

Comment: Have you already tried to implement this repo into your project?

Comment: Yep pedro i add in my project but i dont know how i connect a cell of this array in another view in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`, that you already implemented in ExpandableTableViewViewController.swift.

There, you can add a segue to your Main View Controller, passing it the data.

```
if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDOfYourMainView") as? ResultViewController {
    //Here you can access to the view's functions and attributes. 
    //You can set, for example, an imageView and set it the image you want. 
    //Then, when the view loads (Read next line), it should have your image loaded.
    presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: So Juan  i need to identify the cell to enter in the right segue so if i do this:

selectedCellIdenPath = indexPath

if selectedCellIndexPath == "Num 1"
         if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDOfYourMainView") as? ResultViewController {
   
    presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)}

In theory works?

Comment: I'm not sure about the `if selectedCellIndexPath == "Num 1"`. Try to use `selectedCellIndexPath.row == 1` if you're trying to get the row #1.